# Can I use logical equivalence instead of biconditional in proofs?

Tags: logic, proof-writing

My textbook defines the symbol *<=>* to mean *equivalent to*, *has the same solutions as* or *if and only if*. It defines the symbols *=>* and *<=* to mean *implies* or *leads to*. The textbook does not use the symbols *<-*, *->* or *<->*.

---

When it shows me how to prove

*x is even <=> x^2 is even*

it says i must prove one direction =>, and then the other direction <= (the converse).

---

What I'm struggling to understand is why I cannot simply write

*(x = 2k) <=> (x^2 = (2k)^2 = 2(2k^2) = 2s , where s = 2k^2 which is an element of the integers)*

to prove

*x is even <=> x^2 is even*

The two equations *x = 2k* and *x^2 = (2k)^2* have the same solution. Therefore, by the textbook's definition I can put the symbol *<=>* between the equations. Thus, by the textbook's definition of the symbol *<=>* I have shown that *x is even if and only if x^2 is even*.

Comment: In this case it's possible, but in more complicated cases, it's more or less impossible to prove both implications at once. Therefore, I suspect that the book wants you thinking that way straight away.

Comment: Also, say you have three claims $a), b)$ and $c)$ that you want to prove to be equivalent. Then it can be proven by showing $a) \implies b) \implies c) \implies a)$. This, of course, works just as well with more than three claims. Some examples of this is the invertible matrix theorem (which is a long list of equivalent conditions given a square matrix), and Axiom of Choice $\Leftrightarrow$ Well-ordering Principle $\Leftrightarrow$ Zorn's Lemma.

Answer (score 1):

If this was an exam I am correcting, I would accept your answer for proving that if $x$ is even then $x^2$ is even, because I do think you need a couple of more details for the other direction. This is also the point of doing one direction at a time, so you can really see that all details come together and are well motivated, as they may seem too far of a step otherwise (which is what your book is trying to teach you).

An acceptable proof (in my oppinion) for $x^2$ is even implies $x$ is even:

> Assume $x^2$ is even. Then $2$ divide $x^2$ but since $2$ is a prime and $x^2$ is a product $x\cdot x$, $2$ has to divide one of them i.e $2$ divide $x$. Thus $x$ is even.

As Arthur comments; It may also sometimes be more or less hard to actually do the proof of equivalence and it may become much easier to do the implications one at a time instead.